# "Is it right?" or "Is it correct?"

Tags: word-choice, questions

Which question is more proper?

> *[some statement]*, is it right?
>
> *[some statement]*, is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right can be used more often than correct. Correct implies something is absolutely true. Right can be used in matters of opinion.

**edit for referencing**

Let's consider the math problem 2+2. We can use right and correct as follows: "2+2=4, is it right?" "2+2=4, is it correct?" Both are acceptable. However, let's now introduce a matter of opinion - "George Bush invaded Iraq, is it right?" "George Bush invaded Iraq, is it correct?" In this scenario, right is preferable to correct. The definition for each word supports this claim. [Correct is defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/correct) as conforming to or agreeing with fact, logic, or known truth." [Right is defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right) as "being in accordance with what is just, good, or proper."

Comment: Can you please provide some substantiation for that answer, so as to demonstrate that it is not just a "matter of opinion"?

Comment: Of course - my apologies. Let's consider the math problem 2+2. We can use right and correct as follows: "2+2=4, is it right?" "2+2=4, is it correct?" Both are acceptable. However, let's now introduce a matter of opinion - "George Bush invaded Iraq, is it right?" "George Bush invaded Iraq, is it correct?" In this scenario, right is preferable to correct. The definition for each word supports this claim. Correct is defined as "free from error, in accordance with fact or truth." Right is defined as "morally good, justified, or acceptable."

Comment: Thank you, but please (1) amend your answer rather than add a comment; (2) please link to your sources (for your dictionary definition). You might find this help page useful: [How do I write a good answer?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).